# How to split files in PL/SQL based on fixed size

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle's `UTL_FILE` package to generate some files. The file names have a certain format like `<name>_<date>_<time>_<sequence>` where `sequence` starts from 000.

Now I want to split the files if the original file is greater than x Mb. In that case I will get (in case of 2 files) :

```
<name>_<date>_<time>_001
<name>_<date>_<time>_002
```

where 001 is 10 Mb (max) and 002 is < 10 Mb.

The only way I see to do this is to count every line in bytes which will be written by the `UTL_FILE.put` command and then to decide whether to write more or to spilt.

This seems me very CPU consuming process.

Is there a way to do this differently in PL/SQL?

Comment: *How to split flies*: That's the most difficult question I've encountered today. :)

Comment: Why is keeping a running total of how many bytes you've written very CPU-consuming? Seems like very little overhead on top of the work you're already doing.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I suppose you could construct your data in memory and only write it to file when adding a line took it over the 10MB threshhold, but that would be even more resource-intensive than simply keeping a counter.

Comment: I have done the first implementation. The problem is additional constraint I have that all product_id must be in one file so not spread across more files. That means I need to count size in bytes of every product_id (doing group by on that) and then check if fits in size of current file then write. In case of only 1 product_id,

Comment: I can take those line directly in the cursor and write it. But if I have more product_id's then need to open cursor again and loop it to get all lines belonging to that product_id. That costs performance. For instance file of 5 Mb with 50% 1 product_id and 50% more, it takes about 4 minutes to write and split. First part is very fast (1 product_id) but second takes 80-90 % of time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough badges to comment. Hence answering.

That's interesting and challenging. But why do you want to do this in PL/SQL only? You can easily achieve this task by writing a shell script.

Let us say the file name is File1 and the size is 5.6GB. Then the file should split into 3 files and the naming of the files should be File1, File2, File3

You can use `du -BG <file>` to get the size in GB.

`size=$(du -BG your_file | cut -dG -f1)`

then

`[ $size -ge 3 ] && split -d -b2G your_file file`

output will be `file00 file01`